# Strongloop / Loopback Getting started missing root.js

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

I'm following the getting started documentation from Loopback, and I have an issue when I want to add static files [Strongloop getting started Step 3](http://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Add+a+static+web+page): the file /server/boot/root.js doesn't exists, in addition /server/server.js does not have the 2 lines that were supposed to be there :

```
//   var path = require('path');
//   app.use(loopback.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '../client')));
```

Instead, the /server/middleware.json shows :

```
"routes": {
    "loopback#status": {
      "paths": "/"
    }
  },
```

Could someone please let me know how to perform this step ? Note : the git repository for Step 3 is good, but not the scaffolded project running slc loopback.

Comment: when i tried to generate the loopback application using slc, it has every thing. Just try generating app using slc without using the example code checked in github. it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The /server/middleware.json file is where middleware is registered now.  The following excerpt is resolving to a file in module's server/middleware directory (loopback-getting-started/node_modules/loopback/server/middleware).

```
"routes": {
    "loopback#status": {
      "paths": "/"
    }
  },
```

Change this to:

```
"routes": {
  },
```

Restart the Loopback server and visiting localhost:3000 results in an Express error 404, which would be expected since you no longer have a route defined for /.

You now need to specify in the middleware.json file how to serve static content.  You do this in the "files" phase:

```
"files": {
  "loopback#static": {
    "params": "$!../client"
  }
}
```

You can now add the following to an index.html file in your /client directory as the original documentation states.

```
<head><title>LoopBack</title></head>
<body>
    <h1>LoopBack Rocks!</h1>
    <p>Hello World... </p>
</body>
```

Restarting the Loopback server and visiting localhost:3000 now serves the index.html page.

More details about how to specify middleware via the new way is located at http://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Defining+middleware#Definingmiddleware-Registeringmiddlewareinmiddleware.json

Also see https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-faq-middleware

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of LoopBack removed the `root.js` file. You do not need it anymore, the docs need to be updated to reflect this.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Following up on this, would you have an example of working static middleware defintion ? I looked here : [Loopback doc](http://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Using+middleware+phases) and this code doesn't work for me : `{
  "files": {
    "loopback#static": {
      "params": "$!../client"
    }
  }
}`